# why do the Interceptor in nest7 not working?

Tags: node.js, nest

I need set the header in all requests, but it's not working. I create the Interceptor with this code:

```js
intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
  const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  request.headers['NewHead'] = 'NewValueHead';
  return next.handle();
}
```

And add in the modules inside providers:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
    useClass: CustomInterceptor,
  }
],
```

I did many tries with postman but the added header doesn't show.